# Spring Boot with maven war dependancy

Tags: maven, spring-boot, war

I have Spring Boot web project with dependency to maven overlay war file which is also Spring web project. War is included in pom.xml.

How can I deploy that war along with Spring Boot application so I can use rest endpoints that belong to war file. I'm trying to start application from STS simply by running it as Java application. While application is starting, I can see only URLs that belong to Spring Boot project, but URLs that belong to war file are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Spring boot does not support that. [See issue here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1030)

Try building a war and deploying it into a container.